Do I need the assumption that $\operatorname{char}(k) = p$ here?
(This is not a homework question, I'm preparing for an exam).
In Lang's Algebra book, Ch 5, Problem 24 (at least in the version I have) we have the following question:

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $t, u$ be algebraically independent over $k$. Prove... $k(t, u)$ has degree $p^2$ over $k(t^p, u^p)$.

Here is my proof.
First, we show that $[k(t, u) : k(t^p, u^p)] \leq p^2$ which we get since $t$ and $u$ are roots to the polynomials $x^p - t^p$ and $x^p -u^p$ respectively.
Next, we'll show the degree is greater than or equal to $p^2$ by finding a linearly independent set of size $p^2$ i.e. $\\{t^a u^b : 0 \leq a, b \leq p - 1\\}$. If we look at the equation
$$0 = \sum_{0 \leq a, b \leq p-1} c_{a, b} t^a u^b$$
then any coefficients, $c_{a, b} \in k(t^p, u^p)$ which solve this are of the form
$$c_{a, b} = \sum d_i t^{n_i} u^{m_i}$$
for some finite sum. But, if we plug that back in and expand, we get that
$$0 = f(t, u)$$
where $f \in k[x, y]$ which is not possible since $t, u$ are algebraically independent. $\square$
So, I'm pretty confident in this proof, but if its wrong, please let me know. Otherwise, my question is, where did I use the assumption that $\operatorname{char}(k) = p$?

I think part (b) is where you really need this assumption! Part (a) is only there to draw your attention to exactly what this serves as a counterexample to..

For those with no access to the book, Par (b) asks to show "There exist infinitely many extensions between $k(t,u)$ and $k(t^p, u^p)$".

Thanks @IzaakvanDongen! That makes sense to me. If you want to put this as an "official" answer I can make it correct.

No worries. I don't think I'll write an answer - feel free to accept Just a user's answer if you find it satisfactory!

I'd like to add more details to your proof of $\{t^au^b\}_{0\le a,b<p}$ are linearly independent.
Assume $\sum_{a,b}c_{a,b}t^au^b=0$, we want to show $c_{a,b}=0$.

By multiplying the product of all denominators of $c_{a,b}$ (and use the fact that there is no zero divisor in a field), we may assume $c_{a,b}\in k[t^p,u^p]$ instead of $k(t^p, u^p)$. Now we have $\sum c_{a,b}t^au^b=0$ as a polynomial of $t,u$.

Consider the collection of all terms in the sum whose $t$ degree is $a\text{ mod } p$ and whose $u$ degree is $b\text{ mod } p$, this must be $c_{a,b}t^au^b$, because the $t$ degree and $s$ degree of $c_{a',b'}$ are multiples of $p$ for all $a',b'$. Therefore $c_{a,b}t^au^b=0$ and because $k[a,b]$ is an integral domain, $c_{a,b}=0$.


This indeed works without assuming $\text{char}(k)=p$.

Here is another proof: We just have to show $[k(t, u^p):k(t^p, u^p)]=p$, since if this is true, as $k(t, u^p)\simeq k(t,u)\simeq k(t^p, u^p)$, by the same argument, it can also be shown that $[k(t,u):k(t, u^p)]=p$. For this, we may show $1, t, \cdots, t^{p-1}$ are linearly independent over $k(t^p, u^p)$ as above, but $\text{char}(k)=p$ can help an alternative approach:
As $t$ is a zero of $x^p-t^p=(x-t)^p$, the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $k(t^p, u^p)$ is a divisor of $(x-t)^p$, say $(x-t)^m$. Then $m>1$, since $t\not\in k(t^p, u^p)$. If $1<m<p$, then $((x-t)^m)'=m(x-t)^{m-1}$ is also a nonzero polynomial over $k[t^p, u^p]$, that also has $t$ as a root, contradicting the minimality of $(x-t)^m$. While this is unnecessary, it's a useful trick (taking derivative in characteristic $p$) in many other cases.
